# RSA: deduce the public key from message & signed message

Tags: rsa

In RSA, is deducing the **public key** from the `(message, signed message)` pair possible? If so, how can it be done?

Comment: If this is only information, the simple answer is no? But, in general, the public keys are 3, 5, 17, 257, and 65537

Comment: @kelalaka: the public key in generally taken to be the _pair_ $(N,e)$.

Comment: @fgrieu So, there is no way to find $N$ here, you say.

Comment: One idea: of you're able to observe many signed messages, then you could take the maximum of them get a lower bound on $N$.

Comment: But the question did not mention multiple messages, it said **the**

Comment: Could [my question here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/33642/given-enough-rsa-signature-values-is-it-possible-to-determine-the-public-key-va) be considered a dupe?

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes: There are significant differences. [Your question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/33642/555) does not explicitly state that the message is available, and states that RSASSA-PSS signature is considered. Here the message is a given. I seen nothing working well with RSASSA-PSS.

Comment: @fgrieu It doesn't state that it isn't available either, and most messages are available for signature verification. And yes, my question mentioned PSS as one of the PKCS#1 signature schemes, but it explicitly doesn't limit any solution to PSS. There is however no reason to be too strict and I don't see how voting to close it as a dupe is constructive at this point. TL;DR everything is fine.

Comment: @Maarten Bodewes: on second thought, you are right, this a duplicate enough and could be closed. And with minor tuneup my answer could fit your question. [vote to close] Ah, I'm not getting used to my vote being enough to close a question.

Comment: Yeah, very useful on SO for crypto questions, but not that useful here, we don't have any queue for Close Votes to speak off. Maybe a topic for Meta; it gets too inconvenient we could maybe restrict the power to close for gold medals for our specific site. I'll be in the same "trouble" for encryption related questions not too long from now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With only one (message, signature) pair $(M,S)$, it is not known how to recover the public key $(N,e)$. However, that can be done

- with two distinct pairs $(M_0,S_0)$ and $(M_1,S_1)$,
- and assuming a known *deterministic* RSA signature padding scheme with appendix, including textbook RSA, hash-then-textbook-RSA, [RSASSA-PKCS1-V1_5](https://tools.ietf.org/pdf/rfc8017.pdf#page=35) (which is believed safe), and a few others (but not standard [RSASSA-PSS](https://tools.ietf.org/pdf/rfc8017.pdf#page=32)).

In a deterministic RSA signature padding schemes, the signature of message $M$ is computed by transforming it into a padded message representative $\widetilde M$, then computing the signature $S={\widetilde M}^d\bmod N$. The signature verification step verifying alleged $M'$ against $S$ computes $\widetilde{M'}$ and checks $S^e\bmod N=M'$. Computation of the padded message representative typically involves hashing. Textbook RSA has $\widetilde M=M$, while hash-then-textbook-RSA has $\widetilde M=H(M)$ for some hash function (the fist is unsafe, and the second is only safe for very wide hash).

The attack needs to guess $e$, but that's typically a small integer, often $e=F_i=2^{(2^i)}+1$ with $0\le i\le4$, or [$e=37$](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/30825/555), with $e=F_4=65537$ common in practice. We need to pad the two messages $M_i$ into their message representatives per the padding algorithm used by the signature scheme, giving $\widetilde{M_i}$ (for RSASSA-PKCS1-V1_5, we need the size of $N$ in octets, which is the same as that of the $S_i$ if expressed as fixed-size octet strings, or typically given by the highest $S_i$ otherwise).

We are now trying to solve a system of two equations with only unknown $N$: $S_i^e\bmod N=\widetilde{M_i}$. In each, if we got $e$ right, $N$ is a divisor of $(S_i^e-\widetilde{M_i})$.

$N$ can often be found by computing the Greatest Common Divisor of the two $(S_i^e-\widetilde{M_i})$. In most of the remaining cases, pulling out a few small factors from this GCD by trial division of small primes will reveal $N$. For random parameters, this almost always works. The only implementation difficulty stems from the size of $S_i^e$, especially for $e=F_4=65537$ (Java's BigInteger gets impractically slow; GMP shines). Much larger $e$ would make the attack difficult.

If we make a wrong guess of $e$, the method fails (typically yielding a much too small GCD), we can detect that and try another $e$.

Note: at least for textbook RSA, it is possible to intentionally pick messages making pulling out small factors difficult. In that case, [Pollard's rho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm) or [ECM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic-curve_factorization) (as in [GMP-ECM](https://gforge.inria.fr/projects/ecm)) could come to the rescue.

Note: I have included a small demo in Java as invisible text at the end of the [source of the present answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/ccf52beb-8271-46ce-9c43-9093193cd53b/view-source).

Comment: thanks you, this was what I was looking for. Addressing the comment from @kelalaka, if the public key and the private key are interchangeable, would this be a viable attack to find the private key as well?

Comment: @B.Li could you update the quesion as **pairs** etc, so that one can deduce that you have multiples.

Comment: @B.Li interchangeable means you can swap them in the beginning. nothing special, but the pk must be random, too.

Comment: @fgrieu is there a code example for this around somewhere?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why a Fermat prime is normally used for $e$?

Comment: @B.Li: yes: $e=2^k+1$ gives the smallest ratio of number of modular multiplication ($k+1$) to $\log_2(e)$ (about $k$); prime $e$ allows a slight simplification in selection of primes $p$ and $q$; and Fermat primes are the only primes of the form $2^k+1$.